# How to edit Full-text search to look for for exact word?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, full-text-search

I am using a full-text search function to make searches in my blog site. I want to fnd the exact word that is used in my query.

```
$results = DB::table('posts')->whereRaw("MATCH(title,content) AGAINST ('+{$query}*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)")->select('title')->get();
```

Can you show the right way to do it ?
Thanks

Comment: That's a database class so without seeing how it works, it's hard to tell

Comment: it is from laravel framework.. "MATCH(title,content) AGAINST ('+{$query}*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)" this part searches all the text .. but I need it to look for a whole word not a part of a word.

Comment: Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965222/find-exact-match-using-full-text-search can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i was having same problem.

i got solution  by :

$terms = mysql_real_escape_string($terms);

$contact_results = Contact::where_account_user_id(Auth::user()->account_user_id)

```
    ->raw_where("match (`first`, `last`) against ('{$terms}*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)")

    ->where_deleted(0)

    ->paginate(20);
```

phpconsole($contact_results->results);

return $contact_results;